# Error Installing pymssql on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, osx-yosemite, pymssql

I receive the following error when installing pymssql on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 - has anyone gotten around the following error? I am using FreeTDS (v0.91.112) version 7.1 and Python 2.7.6 - the tsql utility connects to a SQL Database with no issue.

`sudo pip install pymssql`

**Error**:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-T5Usla/pymssql/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n',
'\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-uZGqK4-record/install-
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error
code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-T5Usla/pymssql
```

Comment: This error is pretty hard to read.

Comment: That doesn't look like the real error, but instead a failure pip doesn't fully report when trying to delegate building to pymssql. I suggest you try & download pymssql as source distribution & build it yourself using `python setup.py build` - most likely that tells you more about the root cause.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to install pymmsql on your Mac for Azure SQL DB by following these three steps.

Step 1: Install Homebrew
Go to your terminal and run the following command :

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Step 2 : Install FreeTDS.
From the terminal run the following command :

```
brew install freetds
```

This should install freetds on your system

Step 3 : Install pymmsql. From the terminal run the following command

```
sudo -H pip install pymssql
```

Now you should be able to use pymssql to connect to Azure SQL DB and SQL Server.