# How to install pymssql on MacOS Sierra

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, macos, pymssql

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-J1I0ox/pymssql/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qmtdBW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-J1I0ox/pymssql/
```

I am having the same error as displayed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646171/error-installing-pymssql-on-mac-os-x-yosemite) . I followed the instructions on that page by trying `brew install freetds` followed by `sudo -H pip install pymssql`.

That generates this error code:

```
    _mssql.c:18814:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'DBVERSION_80'
    __pyx_r = DBVERSION_80;
              ^
4 warnings and 1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-J1I0ox/pymssql/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qmtdBW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-J1I0ox/pymssql/
```

Searching this error brought me to  [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771434/mac-pip-install-pymssql-error). I followed the solution posted there by trying both  `brew unlink freetds; brew install homebrew/versions/freetds091` and  `brew uninstall freetds; brew install homebrew/versions/freetds091` which generates a different error when trying  `sudo -H pip install pymssql`:

```
_mssql.c:266:10: fatal error: 'sqlfront.h' file not found
#include "sqlfront.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/_s/27xppw4j3yl78c9l4v1w3n9m0000gn/T/pip-build-97A9sQ/pymssql/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/_s/27xppw4j3yl78c9l4v1w3n9m0000gn/T/pip-0nUZo4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_s/27xppw4j3yl78c9l4v1w3n9m0000gn/T/pip-build-97A9sQ/pymssql/
```

So then I gave up and tried to install pyodbc, but I still get similar errors:  `src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: 'sql.h' file not found
    #include sql.h`

Any help with this would be great.

Comment: Have you tried to install `unixodbc` through brew (`brew install unixodbc`)? It contains a `sql.h` you are missing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[This link](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/129)  ended up solving my problem. For anyone else having these issues, this sequence of commands worked for me.

```
brew uninstall --force freetds
brew install freetds@0.91
brew link --force freetds@0.91
pip install pymssql
```

Comment: The above problem is still a problem as of 2018.03.  The steps above worked great!  Thank you!

Comment: I had to `brew link --overwrite freetds@0.91 --force` to get the linking working on MacOS 10.12.6.

Answer (score 12):

As of Feb 2021

I can no longer install freetds@0.91 as homebrew does not have it available. The current version of freetds is 1.2.18 and `brew link --force freetds` doesn't seem to change anything.

The root issue `'sqlfront.h' file not found` is due to the freetds files not linking properly during installation. We can fix this by doing

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/freetds/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/freetds/include"
pip install pymssql
```

Where `/opt/homebrew/opt/freetds` is where homebrew installed freetds on your system (I am on Apple Silicon) and may be different for you. If you are on Intel your's might look something like `/usr/local/opt/freetds`.

To find exactly where homebrew installed freetds (or any program for that matter) on your system, you can do

```
brew --prefix freetds
```

This should return something like `/opt/homebrew/opt/freetds` or `/opt/homebrew/opt/freetds@1.2.18`. You can ignore any version numbers and append `/lib` and `/include` to get the paths you need.

This is a handy trick to keep in mind as it is applicable to lots of other install issues with dependencies installed via homebrew.

Comment: This resolved the issue I was having, macOS 12.3 on Apple M1 silicon, Python 3.9.10.  I had installed FreeTDS with brew, but was still having the issue, after bringing in the environment variables in that terminal I was able to pip install pymssql.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me on Mac M1