# Unable to install pyodbc or pymssql on mac sierra

Tags: python, pyodbc, freetds, pymssql

I am trying to install pyodbc or pymssql python library using  "pip install pyodbc" and "pip install pymssql". However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/mz/2w0c0vc93bb2qy5rmrnxn85h0000gn/T/pip-build-upWR3q/pymssql/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/mz/2w0c0vc93bb2qy5rmrnxn85h0000gn/T/pip-DUorxp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/mz/2w0c0vc93bb2qy5rmrnxn85h0000gn/T/pip-build-upWR3q/pymssql/
```

I already have freetds installed although I am still getting the following message during installation:

```
setup.py: Detected Darwin/Mac OS X.
        You can install FreeTDS with Homebrew or MacPorts, or by downloading
        and compiling it yourself.

        Homebrew (http://brew.sh/)
        --------------------------
        brew install freetds

        MacPorts (http://www.macports.org/)
        -----------------------------------
        sudo port install freetds

    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
```

Anyone had any idea why is that so?
I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958536/how-to-install-pymssql-on-macos-sierra), [this solution](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/python/pyodbc.html) and [this solution](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Mac-OSX).

This is my current FreeTDS settings:

```
                        Version: freetds v0.91.112
         freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/Cellar/freetds@0.91/0.91.112/etc
 MS db-lib source compatibility: no
    Sybase binary compatibility: no
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: yes
                    TDS version: 7.1
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: no
          SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                       Kerberos: no
```

I can't install unixodbc either:

```
pip install unixodbc
Collecting unixodbc
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unixodbc (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for unixodbc
```

Please help?

Comment: What version of Python are you using (`python --version`)? Are you using a `virtualenv`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install it by doing this:

1. Install unixodbc with `brew install unixodbc`
2. Install iodbc: http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads
3. Install the MySQL driver: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/
4. Add the driver with `myodbc-installer -a -d -n "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver" -t "Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5w.so"`
5. See that `/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini` and `/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini` have been updated
6. Now point unixodbc's odbcinst.ini/odbc.ini files to instead use the iodbc ini files:
7. `sudo rm /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbc.ini && sudo ln -s /Library/ODBC/odbc.ini /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbc.ini`
8. `sudo rm /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbcinst.ini && sudo ln -s /Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini  /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbcinst.ini` .
9. Install pyodbc: `pip3 install pyodbc`.
10. Launch a python shell (`python3`) and check that you can find the driver (`import pyodbc;pyodbc.drivers()`)

I hope this can help someone.